# Is DC motor on relay coil side ok?

Tags: relay, dc, dc-motor

I am trying to use a 9.5A (max) 12v DC motor in the circuit of the coil side of a 10A 12v DC relay and although its opening the NC contacts, its not allowing the motor to run. What i'm trying to do is cut off an irrigation solenoid whenever the 12v DC motor is actually running, so as to avoid a sudden loss of pressure.
Am I missing something basic here?
[image: motor not running here..]

Comment: A schematic of your circuit and links to the datasheets for your relay would help us to give you a better answer to your question.

Comment: If the motor is in series with the relay coil, the coil will not pass enough current to allow the motor to operate - with a 12 volt supply, you may find 11 volts across the relay coil, leaving only 1 volt for the motor (numbers are a wild guess - you'll probably have much less than a volt across the motor).  Find a datasheet for the relay - you'll probably find that the coil requires much less than 1 amp at 12 volts.

Comment: The datasheet is here http://www.baileyproducts.com/files/87452402.pdf. Its the FRM3W-2B10. Im unsure of how to post a diagram here, but it is hooked up in series with the dc motor, on the coil side.

Comment: @Daryl you must be careful in Relay selection for DC motors  due to the surge currents greatly exceed the average max load by a factor of 5 to 10 x

Comment: Check the DC resistance of the coil for your relay PN. Consider how that relates to what Peter said.

Comment: Would there be another way I can trigger the relay when the motor is running, without stealing power from the motor? Wire it up differently perhaps? (ie in parallel)

Comment: If the motor and relay are both rated to operate on 12 volts, you can (and should) connect them in parallel.  According to the datasheet, the relay will only draw 75 mA, which is insiginificant compared to the motor's 9.5 Amp.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help/advice. Would you have a link/diagram of such a parallel relay circuit setup?

Comment: Please add a freewheeling diode across the motor to save/increase the life of the relay. It does not solve this issue but once you get it running, you will wear out your relay prematurley.

Comment: @Daryl , you are missing a few more things, solenoid power control specs, snubber, DC motor rated relay specs (do NOT use a 10A relay, maybe 25A! ) if solenoid is 12V then a SPDT relay form is what you want not DPDT then a timer relay for solenoid

Comment: @TonyStewart , solenoid is only 1A. I didn't think I had to use a snubber on the coil-side circuit? Also i'm linking across and using both contacts to try and extend their life. Is that ok to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relay coil should be connected in parallel with the motor, and the relay contacts connected in series with the irrigation solenoid, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJD4s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly sure this should work now. I trialled it on a breadboard with similar components. Seems I should have connected the relay in parallel.
[image]

Comment: The relay *coil* goes across the motor.

Comment: motor should be always on in this case, except if your relay connections on the other side are shorting the PSU